# Laravel 5.1 AuthController contains 5 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have deleted the vendor folder and recreated it using composer install yesterday and it was working fine (probably cached). Today I'm facing this error.

> FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 84: Class
>   enterglobe\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController contains 5 abstract
>   methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the
>   remaining methods
>   (enterglobe\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::toArray,
>   enterglobe\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::getKey,
>   enterglobe\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::getTable, ...)

I tried deleting it and installing, also composer dump-autoload also cleared composer cached files to install another version of laravel but with no success.

The error disappears if i just implement the methods on this class for example

```
public function toArray(){}
public function getKey() 
etc...
```

Error goes away from AuthController but then it appears in other controllers.

Anyone faced this before.

Comment: Does your Controller  extends 'BaseController' 
or the abstract class 'Controller' ?

Comment: controller.php -> abstract class Controller extends BaseController
API/UserController.php -> class UserController extends Controller

It does actually I checked that too, anyway I've used my last commit and deleted the project and went on and cloned from my repository it does work actually, but the problem is the that i didnt change anything from  last commit i made yesterday which is this one that i cloned. Anyways thank you.